# Is there a way to output to csv from gcloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I'm trying to find an easy way to periodically run a check on unattached disks across all my projects.

All I am doing is just open the cloud shell terminal in GCP and use the following CL:

```
gcloud compute disks list --filter="-users:*"
```

Is there a way to run this across all projects and then output to csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack overflow encourages questions where an attempt is document to solve the problem for yourself.

If you Google `gcloud csv`, the [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=gcloud+csv&oq=gcloud+csv) include several explanations of how to do this.

Google documents [`gcloud topic formats`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) and this includes [`csv`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats#csv).

To understand the shape of Google's resources, check out [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer). It documents every Google service. For [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1), you can find the equivalent `gcloud compute disks list` by appending `--log-http` and observing which API calls are made... it's [`disks.list`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/list) and this is its [response body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/list#response-body). This describes the output of the `gcloud disks list` command when you apply `--format`.

To run the command for all (accessible to your credentials) Google Projects, you must enumerate the Projects. Unfortunately, if it is not enabled, the Compute Engine service prompts. To avoid that, I've added a check.

```bash
# List Projects accessible to these credentials
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

# Iterate over each Project
for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  # Check Compute Engine service
  ENABLED="$(\
    gcloud services list \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --filter=config.name=compute.googleapis.com \
    --format='value(state)')"
  # Is it enabled?
  if [ "${ENABLED}" = "ENABLED" ]
  then
    # Enumerate Disks that have `users` and output `name`
    gcloud compute disks list \
    --project=${PROJECT} \
    --filter="-users:*" \
    --format="csv(name)"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did give it a shot with for project in  $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")

do

echo $project

gcloud compute disks list --filter="-users:*"

done. Yours obviously worked way better. :) I'm going to use that going forward.